# cookie value depends on including 'index.php' in URI

Tags: php, cookies

I have got simple 'index.php' for detecting cookie values:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

When I invoke it form the browser like that http://dev.isos.org.pl/index.php
I get the  following answer:

```
string(10) "/index.php"
array(2) {
  ["ISOSid"]=>
  string(32) "ba130ff42c56a22b85adc5952e0f0fbb"
  ["ISOSnonce"]=>
  string(8) "11193333"
}
```

When I invoke it without 'index.php': http://dev.isos.org.pl I get different cookie values:

```
string(10) "/index.php"
array(2) {
  ["ISOSid"]=>
  string(32) "4d3d82fc3c99c301663ee3831986ffa8"
  ["ISOSnonce"]=>
  string(8) "53268338"
}
```

Such behaviour is unexpected and not desired. How to correct it - to get the same values each time?

Comment: Weird. Cookies change every time you open your browser... Did you close the browser between surfing to these URLs?

Comment: No, not at all. It seems also very weird too me..

Comment: Where are these cookies generated? Hard to detect without further info

Comment: These cookies are generated in another php script via call `setrawcookie("ISOSid", $sid  , time()+60*60*24*365, '/', null, null, true)`. As you  can see, they have permanent status (expire in 1 year). I have expected, that each time old cookies will be replaced by new values. Meanwhile, there are two different set of cookies in place where one can expect just one.